# How to Linq through DataGrid SelectedItems in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I am trying to do:

```
bool hasXItems = (grid.SelectedItems as IEnumerable<Y>).Any(i => ((Y) i).IsX);
```

This does not seem to work (result of casting is `null`). How can I query the `DataGrid.SelectedItems` with Linq?

This is the property I'm querying: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.multiselector.selecteditems(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: What do you want to find out using LINQ?

Comment: I want to know if any of the selected items possess a particular property being `true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cant make out from your comment what you want to do but you can use LINQ this way.

```
DataGridRow[] results = datagrid.SelectedItems
                                .OfType<DataGridRow>()
                                .Where(x => ((bool)x.IsFocused))
                                .ToArray();
```

It will iterate through all selected Rows and return that rows which are focused.

This query has 4 sections

1. `datagrid.SelectedItems`. This line will give all selected rows as a list because SelectedItems returns an IList object.
2. `.OfType<DataGridRow>()` . This line will return all selected rows returned from line 1 as DataGridRow.
3. `.Where(x => ((bool)x.IsFocused))`. This line will iterate over all DataGridRows returned from Line 2 to find which rows is focused.
4. `.ToArray()`. This line will convert all of DatagridRows which are focused returned by Line 3 to Array and put it in the results variable.

Comment: `.OfType<X>()` was just what I was looking for!

Comment: Yes, there's just this "minimum timeout".

Answer (score 2):

If your .IsX() means "is X",

```cs
grid.SelectedItems.OfType<X>().Any();
```

Otherwise,

```cs
grid.SelectedItems.OfType<Y>().Any(item => item.IsX());
```